# When using Azure Batch Processing, what is the best way to create and use a configuration file which can change per instance?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration, azure-batch

So I'm new to Azure and currently working on a project in which I will be using azure batch processing to run an application in several instances with different configurations.

I was wondering what is the best practice for doing this, with reference to how easy it is to change the configuration files, to deploy, how to interlink them with source control etc.

Any thoughts/knowledge would be helpful as I can't seem to find much based Azure batch and configuration files.

Comment: When you said application, you mean batch, job ?

Comment: Hiya @gn12345, can you please elaborate little more on your use case. `What is the application for?` || `What is the end result you are expecting?` || `User scenario you are trying?` please lemme know I might be able to help you out man! Thanks, ^Tats

Answer (score 0):

You would manage configuration in the batch client which is a normal application running on the client outside of batch job. This application creates pools, jobs and tasks i.e. sends them to Batch Queue. You can store configuration for this client in a usual way you are used to (app.config, json files etc.).

Scheduling a job to run in batch involves specifying job parameters like pool id, task id, resource files etc. and **command line** for an executable to run. This is where you pass required parameters for a task **instance** to use.